# SelectetValue does not return the selected value in ASP.NET DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

I'm slowly going mad over the following problem: In my ASP.NET page (target: .NET 4.0) I have the following declaration of a `DropDownList`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbRequestState" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Pending" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Open" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Closed" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In the `Page_Load` event in code-behind I set the `cmbRequestState` value to "2" for example - everything's fine, the value shown in the combo box in the browser is "Closed", as the respective `<option>` tag in HTML has the `selected="selected"` attribute.

Then I select "Open" and perform a postback using a "Save"-button on my page. When I retrieve the `SelectedValue` for `cmbRequestState` in the button's code, it is still "2" even though I've selected "1".

Now I don't write ASP.NET applications too often, but I do have some knowledge in HTML and PHP programming and from my WinForms and WPF background I'd expect the `SelectedValue` to contain the value that is currently selected... Also, I do not want to perform a postback every time a user selects a value from the list.

What am I missing here? How would I make sure that when opening the page, the current request state  is selected and still get the new selection if the user makes a change?

Comment: Can you add your code-behind (at least the relevant parts of Page_Load)?  Sounds like you're not checking, in the Page_Load method, whether the request is a postback or not.  Are you checking `IsPostback`?

Comment: No, I did not check that... As I said below: *FACEPALM*, and thank you also for the answer.

Comment: haha, didn't understand FACEPALM at first, thought it was a cool acronym I haven't heard of :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), the selectedvalue you are assigning in the `Page_Load` event overwrites the value you are setting in the button's `OnClick` event. You should try to match the page lifecycle when assigning values to your controls.

Comment: 1) *FACEPALM* - Thanks! 
2) Repeat from 1)

Answer (score 3):

In Page_Load, do a check if it's a postback request. If it is, don't initialize your combo box.

```
if (!IsPostback) {
    cmbRequestState.SelectedValue = "2";
}
```